# Live output from Python database query

Tags: python, database, sybase, output, sap-ase

I have a piece of code looking like this:

```
 conn=sybpydb.connect(user=args.u, password=args.p,servername=args.s)
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute(sql)
 print(cur.connections.messages)
```

The execute takes maybe 5 minutes to run, and then it prints my output.
I was wondering if there is any way to print the output line for line while the execute is running instead of waiting until it is done and getting it all as one big batch?

Comment: Did you try to iterate over your cursor?

Comment: I think you need smth like a server-side cursor functionality. For example, MySQLdb interface supports it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337479/how-to-get-a-row-by-row-mysql-resultset-in-python. Not sure if sybpydb can handle your case.

Comment: What do you mean when you say iterate over the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

filmor is right : retrieve results running on the cursor.

The sybpydb package is a [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) implementation provided by Sybase. So, the Cursor object you retrieve have some methods, for example fetchone and fetchall.

Your code, to retrieve results line by line and do something with it, would be:

```
# Preparation your connection and cursor for fetching results
conn = sybpydb.connect(user=args.u, password=args.p, servername=args.s)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)

# Reading all result one by one
for row in cur.fetchall():
    # Do something with your current results
    print(row)

# Closing cursor and connection
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: This would fetch one row and print each value.

Comment: @Daniel ... and ? Is this not what asked with " I was wondering if there is any way to print the output line for line while the execute is running" ?

Comment: OP wanted to print the result row by row, your code fetches only one row and then prints each value in that row and then exits

Comment: You're right Daniel. fetchall must be used. I add a correction to the code.