# In Python + MySQL, is it better to use an SSCursor, or to use a paginated Stored Procedure?

Tags: python, mysql, pagination

I'm on Python 2.7 (sigh) and MySQL 5.6.23.

I need to retrieve a lot of data from MySQL using Python.

I read about SSCursors, and I also saw something about creating a paginated query (stored procedure in my case).

Apparently SSCursors have pluses and minuses, as perhaps do paginated queries.

SSCursors don't appear to like concurrency - when using an SSCursor, you can only have one query in flight at a time (?). Also, they appear to be less than portable?

And with paginated queries, I have to wonder what would happen if relevant tables were modified During the query - would you possibly miss a row or get a duplicate row?  Also with paginated queries, I heard that the last page of data takes time proportionate to the entire query, so they might not help me much?

So what's better - SSCursors or Paginated SP's/Queries?  And is the above stuff true?

[How to efficiently use MySQLDB SScursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808150/how-to-efficiently-use-mysqldb-sscursor) is useful and one of my source documents, but does not appear to address paginated queries or portability.

[How to get a row-by-row MySQL ResultSet in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337479/how-to-get-a-row-by-row-mysql-resultset-in-python) is closer.  I added a comment there about the portability of what's discussed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently use MySQLDB SScursor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808150/how-to-efficiently-use-mysqldb-sscursor)

Comment: I'd say there's some overlap, but not quite the same question.